# How I Can Change The Another Component Data on VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a classic Vue Component like this

```
Vue.component('bar', {
    template: `<div class="bar"></div>`,
    data () {
        return {
            blocks: [
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

And also i have  Vue Instance like this.

```
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 1
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
        // here to do
    }
  }
});
```

When add function work, i have to add to data component blocks value. I can't use Vuex and what is this other solutions?

Comment: You should use props instead.

Comment: Well, i'm using that my another child component actually, and my other child component pull the data from blocks value. For that i have to add data to blocks value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a parent -> child communication, you can very simply use [props:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

- Store `blocks` on the parent component.
- Pass `blocks` as a prop to `bar` component.
- Do any additional processing using [computed properties.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- Display data using child's template.

Here's some guiding:

1. Define your component with props:

   ```
    Vue.component('bar', {
        template: `<div class="bar">{{blocks.length}}</div>`,
        props: ['blocks']
    });
   ```
2. Define `blocks` on the parent (in your example, the main vue component):

   ```
    new Vue ({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            blocks: []
        },
        methods: {
            add: function() {
                // do something with blocks
            }
        }
    });
   ```
3. Pass data down to the component:

   ```
    <bar :blocks="blocks"></bar>
   ```

Comment: Well this is not the way i want but it is works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the way which called “Event bus”

https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Or you can create your own state management

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

But i highly recommend you too use vuex, since it will become hard to manage events and state when the project grows

Comment: In my first message, i was say i can't use Vuex or any state managment. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You said i can't use Vuex, but simple state management is not vuex. Check it and see